# Left to right movement animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, user-interface, android-animation

Please have a look at the following code:

**left_to_right.xml (animation)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

**Java code**

```
 animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right);
    animation2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationEvent2());

    private class AnimationEvent2 implements AnimationListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                displayIndex++;
                words.setText(wordList.get(displayIndex));

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }
```

This animation is applied to a `LinearLayout`. When activated, it disappears from the right, but it is not a move. What I want is, when activated, the `LinearLayout` should move from right to left, then disappears from the left corner (still moving until it is 100% away from the view) and when it got disappeared completely, and the same `LinearLayout` should appear from the left side.

This is just like a `HorizontalScroller` where it scrolls away allowing the other object to come into the position. But the issue here is, here the same `LinearLayout` is moving away and coming back.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

left_to_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

right_to_left.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Sample Class Understand it ....

```
package com.test.testproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout ;
    Animation left_to_right_animation;
    Animation right_to_left_animation ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);//intialise your layout
        left_to_right_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.left_to_right);
        right_to_left_animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.right_to_left);
        linearLayout.startAnimation(left_to_right_animation);
        left_to_right_animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                linearLayout.startAnimation(right_to_left_animation);
            }
        });
        right_to_left_animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just Use these kind of things ,May be helpful

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true)       
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(200);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);

    animation.setDuration(200);
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
    Your_Layout.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```